# Suspected multiple account

Tags: discussion

[Difference between main storage and secondary storage and stable storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340211/difference-between-main-storage-and-secondary-storage-and-stable-storage/36453325?noredirect=1#comment60726208_36453325)

Ok, this is the question. Question asker's username is **[suresh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5443453/suresh)**.

I answered on the question Apr 6 at 13:56. and user Damirchi added the part that I've forgot (about stable storage). Then user **[sureshkumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5076313/sureshkumar)** comes, answers question with copy / paste from my answer and adds few more lines. So, that answer gets vote up and accept and also a bounty.

It's not fair, but it doesn't matter. It matters that this is obviously fraud and duplicate account. Also, if you click on **[suresh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5443453/suresh)** it says:

> "Hai i am sureshkumar. I am in chennai. I am working in IT development
>   side."

srsly?

Comment: That's true and probably some accounts need to be burninated. However I notice you copy&pasted that answer as well from elsewhere, in full. You provided some kind of attribution, but we generally frown on answers that rely 100% on external content.

Comment: Yeah, I did because it's question about the storage. I can not redefine the definitions.

Comment: @JosipIvic 1) If you see something like this custom flag it 2) You can give attribution and link to the source from where you got it and write that you didn't wrote that text.

Comment: Sure you can write *your own version* of the definition. Apart from that, if you have to copy&paste an answer 100% then probably the question should be closed.

Comment: See [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: Ok. I putted link below the answer. But that's not the issue here. :)

Comment: 1. `I putted link` -- putting "see here for more" is not the same as saying "content copied and pasted from [source]"; 2. How is sureshkumar copying and pasting your answer any worse than you copying and pasting content from elsewhere?

Comment: jesus christ, I've deleted it now. Can we focus on duplicate account now?

Comment: @TZHX Well, suresh/sureshkumar is likely committing some form of fraud here, so it probably is worse. Also providing *some* link is better than none.

Comment: Success! `This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The suspension period ends on May 12 at 7:34.`

Comment: Vuhu! That's the spirit! :)

Comment: Now, let's go back to work. Cheers.

Comment: I checked sureshkumar's track record because if something like this comes up, there's usually more blatant plagiarism. To my great surprise though, it appears as if he's pretty ok otherwise.

Comment: Look at Oct 12+13 for typical sock puppetry.